# Huge blank gaps randomly appearing

Tags: spacing

I changed my documentclass from article to scrbook. Since I've done this, I am experiencing huge gaps on some pages, sometimes between items, sometimes between equations or paragraphs. I don't understand where this is coming from.

I am using the titlesec package and increased the space between equations slightly, no other modification.
Here you can see what I mean:
[image: Blank space between items]

And here is the corresponding latex code:

```
Der zweite Richtungsvektor der Ebene ist der Vektor $\overrightarrow{AB}$
\begin{align*}
E: &\vec{x} = \vec{a} + s \cdot{\vec{u}} + t \cdot{\overrightarrow{AB}}\\
&\vec{x} = \vec{a} + s \cdot{\vec{u}} + t \cdot{(\vec{b}-\vec{a})}
\end{align*}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{align*}
    &g: \vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        -2 \\
        1
    \end{pmatrix} + s \cdot{\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        3 \\
        2
    \end{pmatrix}}, \qquad B(3|2|2)\\\\
    &E: \vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        -2 \\
        1
    \end{pmatrix} + s \cdot{\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        3 \\
        2
    \end{pmatrix}} + t \cdot{\Bigg(\begin{pmatrix}
        3 \\
        2 \\
        2
    \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        -2 \\
        1
    \end{pmatrix}\Bigg)}\\\\
    &E: \vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        -2 \\
        1
    \end{pmatrix} + s \cdot{\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        3 \\
        2
    \end{pmatrix}} + t \cdot{\begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        4 \\
        1
    \end{pmatrix}}
\end{align*}
\item \underline{Übungsaufgabe: E ist durch g und B festgelegt}
\begin{equation*}
    g: \vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        5
    \end{pmatrix} + s \cdot{\begin{pmatrix}
        -1 \\
        2 \\
        7
    \end{pmatrix}}, \qquad B(2|5|-3)
\end{equation*}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: does the next page start with either a non-floating table or graphic, or a really large math display?  if so, try `\raggedbottom` to see if it changes the spacing.  once you've determined that, there are various methods of dealing with this.  (and other questions have been asked about this situation that have useful answers.)

Comment: Is this all you have in the document? Or do you have something following this environment... like a `figure` that you placed `[H]`ERE...?

Comment: \raggedbottom really worked, but no, afterwards just came a section with normal text, no table, graphic or large equation.